# MKMapView setRegion to Annotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

hy guys. i need some help if u may.  when im pressing the map button i load a object wich has longitude and latitude through a CLLocation property. thing is, i dont want the map to set the region/center coordinate to the user location, i want it to go the the annotation region after the map is loaded, so i do this:

```
- (void)loadActiveEstateAnnotation
{
    RE_Annotation *re_annotation = [[RE_Annotation alloc] init];

     if(self.mapView.showsUserLocation == YES)
         NSLog(@"Santa Clause is comming to town");

    re_annotation.longitude = viewingEstate.estateLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    re_annotation.latitude = viewingEstate.estateLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    re_annotation.poiID = [[RE_Shared sharedInstance] selectedEstate];
    re_annotation.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Estate %d",re_annotation.poiID];

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:re_annotation];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D activeAnnotationCoordonate;

    activeAnnotationCoordonate.longitude = re_annotation.longitude;
    activeAnnotationCoordonate.latitude = re_annotation.latitude;

    MKCoordinateSpan activeEstateSpan;

    activeEstateSpan.longitudeDelta = 0.05;
    activeEstateSpan.latitudeDelta = 0.05;


    MKCoordinateRegion activeEstateRegion;

    activeEstateRegion.center = activeAnnotationCoordonate;
    activeEstateRegion.span = activeEstateSpan;

    NSLog(@"----These are the coordinates%f,%f", activeAnnotationCoordonate.longitude, activeAnnotationCoordonate.latitude);   // coordinates are good and valid ive checked them

    [self.mapView setRegion:activeEstateRegion];
    [self.mapView regionThatFits:activeEstateRegion];
    [re_annotation autorelease];

}
```

So bottom line mapview outlet aint setting the region even tough the coordinates are fine. it does however accept the different spans i gave it but its still always locked on the user region ; question is ...why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happen because your `CLLocationManager` class Update Location every time with your `MKMapView` so here your updated current location are set as region of your MapView

For stop this ,just call this method..

```
[yourLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

in your `loadActiveEstateAnnotation` method at starting.